How to use Custom Serializer using Jackson without a DTO class
The customfilter is not getting triggered/used as the debug point is not getting hit, not sure what I am missing. The requestJson still has the field which I am trying to remove/replace with a value derived on this field.
@PostMapping(path = ["/events"], produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
fun processEvents(@RequestBody request: Any, @RequestHeader headers: Map<String, String>): ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> {
    try {
        val customFilter = object : SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {
            override fun serializeAsField(pojo: Any?, jgen: JsonGenerator?, provider: SerializerProvider?, writer: PropertyWriter?) {
                if (writer?.name == "sensitiveField") {
                    val sensitiveFieldValue = (pojo as? Map<*, *>)?.get("sensitiveData")?.get("sensitiveField")?.toString()
                    val maskedValue = maskSensitiveData(sensitiveFieldValue)
                    writer.serializeAsOmittedField(pojo, jgen, provider)
                    jgen?.writeFieldName("maskedField")
                    jgen?.writeString(maskedValue)
                } else {
                    super.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider, writer)
                }
            }
        }

        val filterProvider: FilterProvider = SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("customFilter", customFilter)
        objectMapper.setFilterProvider(filterProvider)
        val requestJson = objectMapper.writer(filterProvider).writeValueAsString(request)
        LOGGER.info("Request body: {}, headers: {}", requestJson, headers)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        LOGGER.error("Error processing request: {}", e.message)
    }
    val mockResponse = ResponseDto(success = true, error = null)
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(mockResponse)
}

private fun maskSensitiveData(sensitiveData: String?): String {
    // Implement your masking logic here
    return sensitiveData?.takeLast(3) ?: ""
}

data class ResponseDto(
    val success: Boolean,
    val error: String?
)


For some reason I had to call addMixIn function on ObjectMapper and that fixed the issue. Looks like for the custom Filter to work I have to have a class with @JsonFilter to augment the class being serialized
